# Dual-booting Mac OS X and Windows: any way to avoid closing all my applications in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, hibernate, multi-boot

I have a MacBook Pro with Mac OS X 10.6 and a Windows 7 Boot Camp partition. If I'm on Windows, I can easily go back to OS X without losing any of my open applications by using Hibernate. Mac OS X, however, doesn't let you hibernate the computer manually, and I have to close and later reopen all my applications when going from Mac OS X to Windows, which is annoying. Is there any way to force Mac OS X into Safe Sleep, or perhaps a better solution to this problem altogether? Thank you!

Comment: There are programs that will send the computer into Safe Sleep for you, for example the [Deep Sleep](http://deepsleep.free.fr/) widget for Dashboard.

Comment: VMware Fusion and Parallels allow you to run your Boot Camp Windows installation as a virtual machine with Mac OS X as the host system. Depending on what you want to do in Boot Camp (basically everything except games and resource-intensive applications), this might be handy.

Comment: I can't speak for the OP but the reason why I would like this functionality is because I want to play a game in Windows.  :)  Unfortunately, merely relaunching my applications (Terminal and MacVim especially) doesn't restore them to the state that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

http://wiredupandfiredup.co.uk/Relaunch/

> Relaunch saves you time by taking
>   Snapshots of which applications you
>   are using, and starts them back up for
>   you.

Comment: Dead link renders answer useless - maybe should be deleted?